MUTINY TO ENCODE BASE64 better solution?
I want to read a big base64 string and decode them in a String to be saved in a file ( maybe a file in the future). I want to read 4 bytes at a time (because encoded is Base64 ) but in best multithreading fashion. Is it appropriate code or wrong? How to? Thanks!
Optional<String> result1 = convertFileToBase64InStreamingFashion2("c:/temp/prova.txt").collect().asList()
    .await().indefinitely()
     .stream().reduce((acc, el) -> acc.concat(el));
      logger.info(result1.get());
    
    public Multi<String> convertFileToBase64InStreamingFashion2(String path ) throws IOException {
        logger.info("start thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(1);
        return vertx.fileSystem().open(path, new OpenOptions().setRead(true))
                .log()
                .onItem().invoke(
                        x-> x.setReadBufferSize(3*18))
                .onItem().transformToMulti(AsyncFile::toMulti)
                .log()
                .emitOn(managedExecutor)
                .onItem().transform(b ->
                     new Base64().encodeAsString(b.getBytes()))
                .log();

    }

log() prints:
2024-04-17 22:57:01,638 INFO  [org.acm.GreetingService] (Quarkus Main Thread) start thread Thread[Quarkus Main Thread,5,build group]
2024-04-17 22:57:01,639 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (Quarkus Main Thread) Uni.AsyncResultUni.0 | onSubscribe()
2024-04-17 22:57:01,640 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (Quarkus Main Thread) Multi.UniOnItemTransformToMulti.0 | onSubscribe()
2024-04-17 22:57:01,640 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (Quarkus Main Thread) Multi.MultiMapOp.0 | onSubscribe()
2024-04-17 22:57:01,640 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (Quarkus Main Thread) Multi.MultiMapOp.0 | request(9223372036854775807)
2024-04-17 22:57:01,640 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (Quarkus Main Thread) Multi.UniOnItemTransformToMulti.0 | request(16)
2024-04-17 22:57:01,641 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-4) Uni.AsyncResultUni.0 | onItem(io.vertx.core.file.impl.AsyncFileImpl@45a0f69c)
2024-04-17 22:57:01,642 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-4) Multi.UniOnItemTransformToMulti.0 | onItem(#du)
2024-04-17 22:57:01,642 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (executor-thread-1) Multi.MultiMapOp.0 | onItem(I2R1)

..

2024-04-17 22:57:10,150 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (executor-thread-2) Multi.UniOnItemTransformToMulti.0 | request(16)
2024-04-17 22:57:10,152 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-4) Multi.UniOnItemTransformToMulti.0 | onCompletion()
2024-04-17 22:57:10,152 INFO  [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (executor-thread-2) Multi.MultiMapOp.0 | onCompletion()


Is it working? Are you having any issues?

You are approaching this problem in a very weird and counterproductive way.
Multithreading is not a good match for I/O, and you shouldn't be consuming 3 or 4 bytes at a time, but more like 3 or 4 million.

@LouisWasserman you are right but base64 Algorithm works with entire file size or multiple of 3 bytes at time. So, i understood that this is not good for large size files too, but only for read a file with the chunk size choosen by the framework vertx inside...

LouisWasserman  i can update buffer for example 318 or 3100 to be larger!
